# Rails model STI with HBTM relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

So, I have a STI table question like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end

module Questions
 class TeacherSprint < Question
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sprint_users
 end
end

module Questions
 class TeacherSprint < Question
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sprint_users
 end
end
```

I do have more questions but I want that this two have a relation to sprint_users.

But I keep getting this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'teacher_sprint_id' for Questions::TeacherSprint::HABTM_SprintUsers.
```

Every time I tried to add a sprintUser to the model. I also tried to put the relationship in the parent class with same efect and Also I tried to add this to the relationship

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :sprint_users, association_foreign_key: 'question_id', join_table: 'questions_sprint_users'
```

I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure.

Comment: I move the relationship to the parent model and it worked, but is there another way to acomplish it?

Comment: It looks like you need to set the `foreign_key` property on the `has_and_belongs_to_many` statement instead of the `association_foreign_key`